# Spark truncating seconds from datetime

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery, databricks

I have a table in bigquery. Consider that it has one column called "A" whose datatype is datetime. Now, I have a scala-spark job that reads this table. One thing to note is that all values will be of format yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS. Where, HH:MM:SS will always be 00:00:00 . What is happening is, when I read this table in spark, it is interpreting the data as a string and it is truncating the seconds part. So, the output looks something like this: 2011-01-01T00:00 .

I Tried using timestampFormat flag in the options function while reading the table. But, no effect.

Here is the read code:

```
    override def read(spark: SparkSession, readConfig: Map[String, Any]): DataFrame = {
  spark
    .read
    .format("bigquery")
    .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    .option(
      "table",
      readConfig("dataReadProject") + "." + readConfig("dataReadTable")
    )
    .load()
}
```

The spark environment is on Databricks and specifics are
Databricks Runtime Version:
10.4LTS(includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12).

What am I missing here? Any document that explains the issue and its fix would be helpful. Any other details, if required, let me know.

Comment: changing the timestampAsLong  to 'false' instead of date format pattern will print it all as a string (so not truncated)

Answer (score 0):

Note:

I had to pass schema for each table while loading the data via spark. Once, I did that and assigned timestamp as the load datatype for datetime columns, things worked out.